# Can I say がございませんですが？ Does it make sense?

Tags: grammar, sentence, keigo

> アレルギーがございませんですが、何をいただけばいいでございますか。

Does this make sense? I'm trying to write in humble form and trying to connect the two sentences by using が as "but". However, I'm not sure how to use it with でございます。

Comment: Why not simply ございませんが?

Comment: Why would you tell the doctor that you *don't* have allergies, and then ask if you can have something (I assume, some kind of medicine?) *regardless*? What is supposed to be the intended purpose of the 何; and why describe what it *isn't* for, instead of what it *is* for?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, ございませんですが is off the mark.

Incidentally, even if you fix the awkward/comical grammar, it's still weird. In other words, アレルギー**が**ございませんが、何をいただけばいいでしょうか means that you are demanding the listener to offer something substitutable when you find that s/he doesn't have the object called アレルギー despite s/he is supposed to offer it to you.

Comment: Would this make more sense? 「私はアレルギーがござらないで、どんな食べ物をいただけばいいでございますか。」

Comment: No, not at all. What did you mean to begin with? unlike ございます, ござる is not a modern Japanese. Don't use it. In the first place, ございます is not a humble verb but a polite verb. You don't need to use it instead of あります.

Comment: I don't think [アレルギー](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AE%E3%83%BC) is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use 敬語 when talking to a doctor (although you could certainly do it as he is in a position of authority), but you could stick to 丁寧語. To ask if you have any allergies, [you can say](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Are+you+allergic%3F):

> アレルギー体質ですか？